# ¿Cómo configurar el título y subtítulo de un gráfico ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Quisiera ver de que forma centrar el título principal y el subtitulo en un gráfico de barras en ggplot2 como el siguiente:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(
    time = factor(c("dato1","dato2"), levels=c("dato1","dato2")),
    total_bill = c(150, 110)
)
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=time)) + 
    geom_bar(colour="black", fill="#BA8111", width=.8, stat="identity")
```

Comment: ¿De que tipo de gráfico ggplot hablamos? ¿puedes agregar un ejemplo?

Comment: sí, por ejemplo de un gráfico de barras sencillo

Comment: Tipo: **geom_bar()**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Te muestro un ejemplo:

```
library(ggplot2)

dat <- data.frame(
    time = factor(c("dato1","dato2"), levels=c("dato1","dato2")),
    total_bill = c(150, 110)
)
ggplot(data=dat, aes(x=time, y=total_bill, fill=time)) + 
    geom_bar(colour="black", fill="#BA8111", width=.8, stat="identity") + 
    guides(fill=FALSE) +
    xlab("Titulo X") + ylab("Titulo Y") +
    ggtitle("Titulo del gráfico") +
    theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

Los títulos de los ejes X e Y normalmente se muestran centrados, pero el titulo del gráfico no, para centrarlo se puede usar `theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)`

Quedaría así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]